# Having problem deploying node.js application to AWS EB from gitlab pipelines

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, gitlab, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an existing node.js application hosted on gitlab. I try to use gitlab's ci/cd and creating `gitlab-ci.yml`. Having 3 stages namely `build`, `test`, `deploy`, the first two actually works but deploying it to the aws elastic beanstalk im getting an error in the pipelines saying...

```
ERROR: This directory has not been set up with the EB CLI
You must first run "eb init".
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Hope you can help me with my problem :(

this is my sample configuration for my `deploy` stage:

```
  deploy_aws:
  stage: deploy
  image: coxauto/aws-ebcli
  script:
    - mkdir ~/.aws
    - touch ~/.aws/config
    - chmod 600 ~/.aws/config
    - echo "[profile eb-cli]" >> ~/.aws/config
    - echo "aws_access_key_id=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" >> ~/.aws/config
    - echo "aws_secret_access_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" >> ~/.aws/config
    - git checkout master
    - eb deploy sample-sails-app-dev
```

the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are declared in my gitlab's ci/cd variables.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Access and Secret keys are stored in file named credentials. (~/.aws/credentials).

config file has defaults like AWS region & cli output format (json)

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

credentials file have Access & secret id's

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = xx
aws_secret_access_key = xxx
```

So in your deploy script change config directory to credentials

```
- echo "aws_access_key_id=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" >> ~/.aws/credentials
```

Comment: so I only change `- echo "aws_secret_access_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" >> ~/.aws/credentials` this part?

Comment: All 3 lines ----  - echo "[profile eb-cli]" >> ~/.aws/credentials
    - echo "aws_access_key_id=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" >> ~/.aws/credentials
    - echo "aws_secret_access_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" >> ~/.aws/credentials

Comment: the `touch, chmod` part isn't necessary?

Comment: what is in the .gitignore file? .elasticbeanstalk folder should exist.

Comment: You need to create both config and credentials files as mentioned in above answer

Answer (score 0):

`eb` commands require that the PWD be `eb init`-ed just the way `git` commands require that the PWD be `git init`-ed.

Prior to the `eb deploy sample-sails-app-dev`, add `eb init <APP NAME> --platform <PLATFORM NAME>`. This will solve your problem.

Comment: it solved the problem but now i'm getting `ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - No Environment found for EnvironmentName = 'sample-sails-app-dev'.` error. But on my aws eb i have that environment already created.  :(

Comment: You're likely not setting the correct region through `eb init`.

Comment: it's creating a new application version. And the result I'm getting `ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - No Application Version named 'app-c350-190517_055620' found.` I have an existing aws eb environment and I want to deploy the chages to that environment

Comment: The error you are seeing is beside the original question. There's little information to go on to tell why the app version creation is failing. Please create a new question for a clearer explanation and mark this one answered.